# In WPF RichTextBox takes too long to Load when there is no height

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following simple wpf program with a RichTextBox. I just try to load a text file into the RichTextBox. The text file is nearly 82KB and it has 4000 lines.

But the problem is if you don't specify a Height parameter for the RichTextBox it takes more than 10 seconds to show the window. But if there is a Height parameter then it shows the window with the content instantly.

```
namespace WpfApplication1 {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\SSSS\Desktop\WriteLines.txt");
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
            Run run = new Run(text) { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(75, 74, 77)) };
            p.Inlines.Add(run);
            richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Add(p);
        }
    } }
```

//With height parameter, this load with in second

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"  Name="scrolBase" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <RichTextBox Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="richTextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="313"  IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <FlowDocument PageWidth="1000" />
            </RichTextBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

//Without height parameter, this takes 10 seconds to load

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"  Name="scrolBase" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="richTextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="313"  IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <FlowDocument PageWidth="1000" />
            </RichTextBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My real application is much bigger than this(it takes more than 3mins to laod without height and with height less than 20sec), and it took me one and half day to figure out why the application is slow to load. Sometimes this question will be an answer to some others. Do any of you know the reason for this?

Comment: Does the file you are reading quite heavy?

Comment: I've only had one coffee so far this morning, which may be affecting my reading age. It looks a lot like both of your posted samples are identical, with no Height attributes on either RichTextBox. Could you confirm exactly where you're setting Height?

Comment: Wait a minute you posted the same code in both XAML...

Comment: sorry, mistake.... corrected, just the Height parameter in RichTextBox tag.

Comment: @Galm88: I've menthioned that, the file size is 88KB with 4000 lines. I tried several other files, some of them are larger than that, but load quickly. But if there are lots of spaces and new lines, then it takes time.